# Screen scraped records not correctly imported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-table, screen-scraping

I have the following section of code from my screen scraping script (in a Rails 3.1 application):

```
# Add each row to a new call record
page = agent.page.search("table tbody tr").each do |row|
  next if (!row.at('td'))
  time, source, destination, duration = row.search('td').map{ |td| td.text.strip }
  call = Call.find_or_create_by_time(time)
  call.update_attributes({:time => time, :source => source, :destination => destination, :duration => duration})
end
```

This was working but I think a few changes have been made on the remote site (they don't currently have an API).

The new HTML code is as follows:

```
<tr class='o'>
<td class='checkbox'><input class="bulk-check" id="recordings_13877" name="recordings[13877]" type="checkbox" value="1" /></td>
<td>09 Feb 11:37</td>
<td>Danny McClelland</td>
<td>01772123573</td>
<td>00:00:28</td>
<td></td>
<td class='opt recording'>
<a href="/unit/27/logs/recording/13877"><img alt="" class="icon recordings" src="/images/icons/recordings.png?1313703677" title="" /></a>
<a href="/unit/27/logs/recording/13877" data-confirm="Are you sure you wish to delete this recording?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow"><img alt="" class="icon recording-remove" src="/images/icons/recording-remove.png?1317304112" title="" /></a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Since the suspected changes the data is being imported in the wrong fields or being missed completely. Currently the only part of the data I want/need is:

```
<td>09 Feb 11:37</td>
<td>Danny McClelland</td>
<td>01772123573</td>
<td>00:00:28</td>
```

Sadly, those rows don't have any unique identifiers though.

Any help/advice is appreciated!
Is there a better way to write the script that is more 'future' proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first td is a checkbox now.
So just change it to:

```
time, source, destination, duration = row.search('td')[1..5].map{ |td| td.text.strip }
```

There's really no way to future proof a scraper (unless you're psychic)